# Why Unicode Data is stored in numeric form in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

I have this following

```
$html = <div>ياں ان کي پرائيويٹ ليمٹڈ کمپنياں ہيں</div>
```

But it is being stored in the mysql database as following format

```
&#1578;&#1608; &#1610;&#1729; &#1575;&#1587;&#1605;&#1576;
&#1604;&#1610; &#1605;&#1610;&#1722; &#1594;&#1585;
&#1610;&#1576; &#1705;&#1608; &#1570;&#1606;&#1746; 
&#1606;&#1729;&#1610;&#1722;
```

Actually, When I retrieve the data from mysql database and shows it on the webpage it is shown correctly.
But I want to know that Is it the standard format of unicode to store in the database, or the unicode data should be stored as it is (ياں ان کي پرائيويٹ ليمٹڈ کمپنياں ہيں)

Comment: Without seeing your php, we can't tell you.

Comment: this because your HTML page encoding is not UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

When you store unicode in your database...

First off, your database has to be set as 'utf-general', which is not the default. With MySQL, you have to set both the table to utf format, AND individual columns to utf. In addition to this, you have to be sure that your connection is a utf-8 connection, but doing that varies based on what method you use to store the unicode text into your database.

To set your connection's char-set, if you are using Mysqli, you would do this:

```
$c->set_charset('utf8'); where $c is a Mysqli connection.
```

Still, you have to change your database charsets like I said before.

EDIT: I honestly don't think it matters MUCH how you store it, though I store it as the actual unicode characters, because that way if some user were to input '& #1610;' into the database, it wouldn't be retrieved as a unicode character by mistake.

EDIT: Here is a good example, if you remove that space between & and #1610; in my answer, it will be mistakenly retrieved from the server as a unicode character, unless you want users to be able to create unicode characters by using a code like that.

Not a perfect example since stackoverflow does that on purpose, and it doesn't work like that really, but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Something wrong with data charset. I don't know what exactly.
This is workaround. Do it before insert/update:

```
$str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: This could be a bad idea because it will un-convert `&lt;`.

Comment: IMHO you should avoid "bad characters" in right context. Do mysql_real_escape_string() before insert/update and htmlspecialchars() before echo and NEVER vice versa!

Comment: Agreed, but I think OP meant the `<div>` was part of the database data, and perhaps there are other tags with it too. In that case it's meant to be a string of HTML in the database, not a string of text for display on an HTML page.

Comment: @Boann, it is very possible! But we can only assume it. I hope the author will choose appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like to me that this is HTML encoding, the way PHP encode unicode to make sure it will display OK on the web page, no matter the page encoding.

Did you tried to fetch the same data using MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that somewhere in your PHP code [`htmlentities`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) is being used on the text -- instead of [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). The difference with `htmlentities` is that it escapes a lot of non-ASCII characters in the form you see there. Then the result of that is being stored in the database. It's not MySQL's doing.

In theory this shouldn't be necessary. It should be okay to output the plain characters if you set the character set of the page correctly. Aassuming UTF-8, for example, use `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` or `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" value="text/html; charset=utf-8">`.

This might result in gibberish ([mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)) if you view the database *directly* (although it will display fine on the web page) unless you also make sure the character set of the database is set correctly. That means the table columns, table, database, and connection character set all to, probably, `utf8mb4_general_bin` or `utf8_general_bin` (or `..._general_ci`). In practice getting it all working can be a bit of a nuisance. If you didn't write this code, then probably someone in your code base decided at some point to use `htmlentities` on it to convert the exotic characters to ASCII HTML entities, to make storage easier. Or sometimes people use `htmlentities` out of habit when the merer `htmlspecialchars` would be fine.